# Why the Output is yyxz?

Tags: c#

I have written the following Code, But I have doubt in the Output of the following Code.

First Doubt is, When We initialize the Child Class Object, First the Base Class Constructor is called so the OutPut should be xz only. Constructor of Y class should not be called.

Second Doubt is  Y is to be called then the Order should by yxyz.

Please clear my doubt.

```
   class X
        {
            Y y = new Y();
            public X()
            {

                Console.Write("x");
            }
        }

        class Y
        {
            public Y()
            {

                Console.Write("y");
            }
        }

        class Z: X
        {
            Y y = new Y();
            public Z()
            {

                Console.Write("z");
            }
        }
        public static void Main()
        {
            new Z();
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look at [this link on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa645606(v=vs.71).aspx) you will see how the operations are executed:

*Variable initializers are transformed into assignment statements, and these assignment statements are executed before the invocation of the base class instance constructor. This ordering ensures that all instance fields are initialized by their variable initializers before any statements that have access to that instance are executed.*

This means that your order of execution is this:

1. Class Y constructor is called from class Z which prints `y`
2. Base class X constructor is called from class Z, but first it initializes variable of class Y which prints another `y`
3. Base Class X constructor is called from class Z which prints `x`
4. Constructor of class Z is called which prints `z`

Answer (score 1):

Very simply: field initialisers are processed before constructors. Before either of your constructors are called, your lines `Y y = new Y();` are run in both `Z` and `X`.